# Returning MySQL table values from PHP script to Javascript function - Live Graphing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts, livegraph

I have been searching similar problems for hours but with no avail.

I am using Highcharts to update a graph every 3 seconds with the last entry of a specific MySQL table. I am using the example Javascript code as a guide. Here is the snippet of code I am concerned with

```
var chart;
$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: {
      load: function() {
        // set up the updating of the chart every 3 seconds
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {
          var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time - adjust to align with data vals
              y = getyval();
          series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 3000);
```

...where the function `getyval()` uses `$.get()`:

```
function getyval(){
  $.get('testget.php', function(output){
    alert(parseFloat(output));
  });
};
```

My `testget.php` file:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = $_SESSION['monitorId'];
$table = $_SESSION['tableId'];
$split_table = explode("_", $table);
$param = $split_table[1];

$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",$db);
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1";
$lastentry = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die('error reading table');
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($lastentry, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$yval = $row[$param];
echo $yval;    
?>
```

This works all well and good at "alerting" the last value every 3 seconds but when I try to assign the variable `y` to this result, it does not work. For example, if I change the `getyval()` function to:

```
function getyval(){
  $.get('testget.php', function(output){
    return parseFloat(output);
  });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use just return, it'll return from anonymous function, not from `getyval()`.
Second problem is that `getyval()` is asynchronous (you'll not receive value just after calling).
You have to call that function earlier, save its result somewhere and then use it.

```
var yValue = null;
function getyval(){
    $.get('testget.php', function(output){
      yValue = parseFloat(output);
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX methods like `$.get` are *asynchronous*, meaning the script doesn't wait for them to finish. The function you passed to `$.get` *can* return something, but it kind of gets dumped into the bit bucket - there's nowhere useful to return it *to*.

Your code needs a little bit of a redesign to take full advantage of being asynchronous. Change the function inside `setInterval` to this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // current time - adjust to align with data vals
  var x = (new Date()).getTime();
  // we need to do this in here so `function(result)` can use `x`
  $.get('testget.php', function(result) {
  // this gets run when the result is received
    var y = parseFloat(result);
    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
  });
}, 3000);
```

The work is now done when `$.get` gets its result and invokes its function, which is whenever your PHP runs.

(You might be worried that the async stuff will mean data points might be received out-of-order. That won't happen - you're specifying the x-coordinate manually, and each time the outer function is run a new `x` is created. Every `y` will be paired with its matching `x`.)